# My html form clears when I hit submit and try to check for form validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms

When I run my code on chrome and try and enter each input one at a time, when I hit submit, all of my input clears! Help me please

Javascript code :

```
function data_validation()
{
    var sfn = form1.sfn.value;
    var sln = form1.sln.value;
    var sid = form1.sid.value;
    var grad = form1.grad.value;

    var RegExpText = /^[A-Z a-z]+$/;
    var RegExpId = /^[0-9]{6}$/;


    if (!RegExpText.test(sfn))
    {
        alert("Please enter your first name");
        document.form.sfn.focus();
        document.form.sfn.select();
        return false;
    }
    else if(!RegExpText.test(sln))
    {
        alert("Please enter your last name");
        document.form.sln.focus();
        document.form.sln.select();
        return false;
    }
    else if(!RegExpId.test(sid))
    {
        alert("Please enter a 6-digit Student ID");
        document.form.sid.focus();
        document.form.sid.select();
        return false;
    }
    grad = -1;
    for(i=0;i<document.client.grad.length; i++)

        if(document.client.grad[i].checked)
    {
        grad = i;
        var gradYear = document.client.grad[i].value;
    }

    if(grad == -1)
    {
        alert("Please select a grade level.");
        return false;
    }

    else if ((form1.php.checked == "") && (document.client.js.checked == "")     && (document.client.c.checked == ""))
    {
        alert("Please select at least one programming language.");
        form1.php.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Thank you for submitting!");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML: I have tried adding return false to onSubmit and I have also tried many other things. My teacher never taught this and I can't find another answer online that works for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="../common/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type = "text/javascript"  src="../common/validate.js"> </script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Form Validation</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container"><!-- Start wrapper -->
<div id="form_data">
    <form name = "form1" id = "form1" onsubmit = "return data_validation();" method="post">
    <table id="tbl_form_input">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <h1 style="text-align:center;">Student Skills Form</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Student First Name:</td>
            <td><input name="sfn" size="20" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Student Last Name:</td>
            <td><input name="sln" size="20" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Student ID:</td>
            <td><input name="sid" size="6" maxlength="6"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Programming Languages</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="PHP" name="php">PHP<br />
                <input type="checkbox" value="JS" name="js">JavaScript<br />
                <input type="checkbox" value="C++" name="c">C++
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Expected Date of Graduation:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="grad" value="2015">2015<br />
                <input type="radio" name="grad" value="2016">2016<br />
                <input type="radio" name="grad" value="2017">2017<br />
                <input type="radio" name="grad" value="2018">2018</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">
                <input type="submit" name="s" value="Send Data">
                <input type="reset" name="r" value="Clear Data">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
   </div><!-- End form_data id formats -->
</div> <!-- end wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't specified an `action` for the form, so it posts to the current URL, and that reloads the page.

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to separate the process of validating form data and the submitting.

In your code, you do them together. The default behavior of submit button is to upload all your form data and clean all the input data, so it behaves correctly as it is meant to be.

What you need to do to make it work is to add event onto those fields.
You can use jQuery .blur() to do that.

.blur() method will be triggered when the field lost focus. So here is where you should trigger your validation process.

I hope it helps.

Cheers,

---

Update:

Add events to the fields which you need to validate.

For example, you need to do some validation on the sln textbox.

$('input[name="sln"]').on("blur", function(){
.....Your validation here...........
});

By the way, where are the IDs for those input components???(they only have names....)

Comment: What fields do I need to add events too?